# Android Firebase -- Storing Google Profile Picture

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am creating an account setup page for my app. So I am giving an ImageView for setting profile pictures.

I am loading the image in the following way:

```
Glide.with(AccountSetupActivity.this)
                        .load(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl())
                        .into(mCircularProfile); //mCircularProfile is ImageView
```

It works flawlessly. The problem is when i try to store this file.

`mImageUri = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl();`

```
StorageReference filePath
                    = mStorageProfilePicturesRef.child("just a random name for testing");
            //Putting The Image At The Specific File Path
            filePath.putFile(mImageUri)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's the problem exactly?

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between URL and Uri. The error is because you are trying to store the String URL into uri .Convert the Url into Uri.

```
mImageUri =  Uri.parse(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl());
```